# Reading from command prompt

Tags: c, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

I'm just trying to fetch the input from command prompt and want to convert the input to integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)    
{   
    int num;
    if(atoi(argv)==0) 
    {
        printf("Enter the number : ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
    }
    else
    {
        num = atoi(argv);
    }
}
```

Above is what I've tried, and I don't know where I've went wrong.

[image]

For the below code I'm getting the error as showed in the picture. I want to run it in both the way like getting from the command prompt and if there is no input from command prompt the values must be fetched when the program runs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)    
{   
    int num_of_values,sum = 0;
    int i;
    float avg;
    if(atoi(argv[1])==0) 
    {
        printf("Enter the number of values: ");
        scanf("%d",&num_of_values);
        int* sum_arr = malloc(num_of_values*sizeof(int));
        printf("Enter the values: ");
        for(i=0;i<num_of_values;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&sum_arr[i]);
            sum+=sum_arr[i];
        } 
    }
    else
    {
         for (i = 2; i<=argc; i++) {
            sum+=atoi(argv[i-1]);
         }
         num_of_values = i-2;
    }
    avg = sum / num_of_values;
    printf("Sum and Average is %d and %f", sum,avg);
    
   
}
```

Comment: What do you think the statements ```atoi(argv) == 0``` and ```atoi(argv)``` do?

Comment: Before accessing an argument, you should check its validity.

Comment: `argv` is a `char **` but `atoi()` expects a `char *` — so that's a problem.  What do you mean by 'fetch input from command prompt'?  You could check whether `argc == 2` and convert `argv[1]` with `atoi()`, or prompt and read standard input if `argc == 1`, or object if `argc > 2`, for example.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong @TedLyngmo

Comment: @BalajiBaski `if(atoi(argv[1])==0)` converts the first argument on the command line to an integer and compares it with `0`. You haven't checked that you have gotten at least 2 arguments first.

Comment: I thought checking the first argument is enough to find whether an integer is present or not! May I know what you mean by haven't checked that you have gotten at least 2 arguments first. @TedLyngmo

Comment: If `argc < 2` then there is no `argv[1]` so doing `argv[1]` will make the program have undefined behavior. `argc` tells you how many elements there are in `argv`. Always check `argc` before dereferencing elements in `argv`

Comment: Okay I'm getting it. Can you tell me the other way to compare ?

Comment: _"the other way to compare"_ - I'm not sure I understand. What other way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250801/discussion-between-balaji-baski-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In `if(atoi(argv)==0)` you probably want to check how many arguments the user gave at the command line. That's what `argc` is for.
- `num = atoi(argv);` should be `num = atoi(argv[1]);`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int num;
    
    if (argc < 2) {                          // no argument given on cmdline
        printf("Enter the number : ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {        // check that scanf succeeds
            puts("Failed reading a number");
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        num = atoi(argv[1]);                 // dereferencing the second element
    }
    printf("num=%d\n", num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

argv is a pointer. argv[i] is a string. argv[0] will be the program name so argv[1] onwards are the cmd line args.

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)    
{   
    int num;
    if(argc<2)  /* user has not provided any cmd line args */
    {
        printf("Enter the number : ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
    }
    else
    {
        num = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    printf("Number = %d\n",num);
}
```

Comment: You should check that there is an `argv[1]` before trying to convert it — if no argument is provided, then `argv[1]` will be a null pointer, which probably causes a crash.

Comment: What if he forgets to give a command line argument by mistake?

Comment: Doesn't print anything when there are no command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for correct number of command-line arguments before calling `atoi`. If not correct, then throw error and return.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <number>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("num = %d\n", num);
}
```